# get the user course enrol reports from moodle

Tags: php, moodle

I have created one custom application in php(I used moodle sessions).so that when the user is logged in, i have displayed all the courses from Moodle.and  gave one button called `LAUNCH`.so that when user click on the `LAUNCH` it will redirect to scorm package. up to now its working fine.

My problem is,if user logged in as first time and  click on LAUNCH button in my application instead of showing scorm package.it's showing user edit page.but i want to show the course enrol page..

how could i do that...i tried to figure it out from past 2 days..but i couldn't...

Can any one help me..

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead..

problem almost solved..it can redirect me to the enrol page after did this..

the problem is if we add lastname as mandatory field in your application it wont redirect you to the edit page..it directly redirect me to the enrol page from my application..